# poner un div al lado del otro

Tags: html, css, contenedores

como puedo poner un div al lado de otro como muestra la imagen los tres primeros recuadros ya están creados pero necesito otros tres al lado derecho
[image: png]

Answer (score 2):

Puedes intentarlo de dos maneras, primero es con la propiedad **position** (que sería su ubicación con referencia a un punto) o con **display** la cual le da una condición de comportamiento partícular a cada bloque.

```css
    .rojo{
      position:relative;
      height: 100px;
      width: 100px;
      background-color: red;
      border: 2px black solid;
    }

    .blanco{
      position:fixed;
      left: 200px;
      top: 10px;
      height: 100px;
      width: 100px;
      background-color: white;
      border: 2px black solid;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="rojo"></div>
    <div class="blanco"></div>
```

```css
.rojo{
  display:inline-block;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  border: 2px black solid;
}

.blanco{
  display:inline-block;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: white;
  border: 2px black solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="rojo"></div>
<div class="blanco"></div>
```

Te recomendaría revisar un poco más sobre *display* y *position* para que lo adecues a tu necesidad.

Cordial saludo.